# Async Javascript functions, not returning values

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm having an issue that is burning my head. Basically this is the scenario:

I have a `callController()` function, which just simple use the `jQuery.load()` method to load a controller, after loaded, I can play with the returning parameters.

Now... in one of my controllers there is a validation rule I need to check in order to to allow the user to execute certain functionality, however, I create a function like this:

```
function myValRule() {

    var val = callController('blablabla'),
    response = "";
    val.done(function(data) {
        //my business logic
        response = something;
    }
    return response;

}
```

As you imagine, `response`, even if It has a value, it returns `undefined`, so I set a timeout and `console.log()` it and now it has a value, but I cannot make to return this value even if I put the return into the `setTimeout()`. So basically when the method call this function to validate it finds it empty.

Can you point me on some direction to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you're  entirely misunderstanding the concept of asynchronous functions. You also seem to have a major syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember this is asynchronous! The `return response;` is long gone by the time `.done()` is actually called.

if you need the value returned in this fashion, look at either supplying a callback function in your `myValRule` function (that would be called from within `.done()`) or maybe look at using the `$.Deferred` api so you can mimic what `callController(...)` is doing.

Here's an example of both scenarios (with example call to `myValRule`):

#### Callback argument

```
function myValRule(callback){
  var val = callController('blablabla'),
  val.done(function(data){
    var response = /* something */;
    callback(response);
  });
}
myValRule(function(response){
  // here you have response
});
```

#### Using $.Deferred

(I assume it's jQuery since there's a .done call)

```
function myValRule(){
  var df = $.Deferred(),
      val = callController('blablabla');
  val.done(function(data){
    var response = /*something */;
    df.resolve(response);
  }).fail(df.reject);
  return df.promise();
}
myValRule().done(function(response){
  // here you have response
});
```

Comment: @andresmijares25: Not in that same "thread". Your done callback is executed at a different time than the return. And there's no real way to "rejoin" the execution plan once you've used a callback (e.g. deferred/promised/ajax).

Comment: your callback sugestion made the trick, thanks a ton for your time Brad

Comment: The promises approach doesn't seem to have appealed to OP, but it should still be noted that [jQuery promises](http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) [are](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/javascript-promises-and-why-jquery-implementation-is-broken/) [broken](http://www.reddit.com/r/Frontend/comments/1qwcta/youre_missing_the_point_of_promises/). One would be better off using a proper promise library, or ES6 promises if they're available.

Comment: I don't understand reddit users; Just post the original article link, don't make me go to reddit to see nothing more than a title with a link to the _actual_ thing I'm after. (err, it forces you to go to reddit first; Sigh)

Comment: I'm not a reddit user. If you look closely, you'll see that I _did_ post the original article link, as well as a link to a similar article, and a reddit page providing a handy tl;dr version of the first article. Also, when directing a comment at an SO user, I suggest prefacing it with `@username` as you did above, so that they know you've said something to them. :)