# method returns null in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, liferay

I am retrieving the data from the database, the data is coming correctly from the database using ajax, problem is I have tried to store the retrieved data in an array, in the below code `return jsonArray`is getting null. can any one help me?

```
function selectEntities(){
    var jsonArray = [];     
    try{            
        var url = '<%=resourceURL%>';
        var A = AUI();                  
        A.io.request(url,
            {
                data: {
                    cmd:'entities',
                },
                dataType:'json',
                method:'post',
                on: {
                    success: function(event, id, obj) {
                        try{
                            var instance = this ;
                            var jsonObject  = instance.get('responseData');
                            var jsonArrayTemp = jsonObject.objJsonArray ;
                            //alert("From the entities: "+jsonArrayTemp);
                            for(var i=0;i < jsonArrayTemp.length ;i++ ){
                                jsonArray.push([jsonArrayTemp[i][0],jsonArrayTemp[i][1]]);
                            }               
                        }catch(exception){
                            //alert(exception);                 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }catch(exception){
        //alert(exception);     
    }   
return jsonArray ;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what the return value of the ajax call is?

Comment: entitiesJsonObject:....{"objJsonArray":[[1,"User"],[2,"Courses"],[3,"Organization"]]} this is the data actually getting from database. when i print jsonArrayTemp  the following data is displaying  1,User,2,Courses,3,Organization

Comment: possible duplicate of [Async Javascript functions, not returning values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829784/async-javascript-functions-not-returning-values)

Answer (score 2):

`A.io.request` is an asynchronous function. As the function takes some time to execute, single threaded javascripts keeps executing the code below to that function and keep doing other work until the response comes. At the time when the response comes and the results are pushed to the array, the function is already executed and returned.

As a solution you can add the code which handles the returned array inside the success callback function without trying to return..

```
function selectEntities(callback){
     ..............
     success: function(event, id, obj) {
                    try{
                        var instance = this ;
                        var jsonObject  = instance.get('responseData');
                        var jsonArrayTemp = jsonObject.objJsonArray ;
                        //alert("From the entities: "+jsonArrayTemp);
                        for(var i=0;i < jsonArrayTemp.length ;i++ ){
                            jsonArray.push([jsonArrayTemp[i][0],jsonArrayTemp[i][1]]);
                        } 
                        callback(jsonArray); // calling the callback function             
                    }catch(exception){
                        //alert(exception);                 
                    }
                }
  ...........
}
```

And then define the callback function and call..

```
var callback = function (jsonArray) {
        alert(jsonArray);  //code to handle jsonArray
    }
selectEntities(callback);
```

Comment: I have removed the returns statement it is showing undefined

Comment: What is `selectRoles()`? Is it something exactly like `selectEntities()` function?

Comment: var entities=selectEntities(); alert(roles);

Comment: You cannot use the return here. You have to learn about asynchronous behaviour of javascripts... What you can do is something like passing a function to the `selectEntities` to deal with the jsonArray, instead of returning.. I edited the code to explain more what I meant..

Comment: I DONE WHAT EVER YOU SAID :( BUT NOT WORKING, SEE MY JSP HERE..http://pastie.org/9793952

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67454/discussion-between-asr-and-sampath-liyanage).